# Allow Azure function app access to AWS EC2 instance port

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, aws-security-group

My company has an Azure function app that accesses a service on an AWS EC2 instance.
We use an AWS security group to only allow access to the service's port by the 7 possible outbound IP addresses used by the Azure function app. We find these listed in Azure portal.
However when the function app "scales" apparently it can be executed from a list of ~600 CIDR ranges of possible Azure IP addresses, from AzureCloud.eastus2 in my case.
The function app fails to access the needed web service in these cases and fails.
AWS security groups only allow 60 inbound rules so I couldn't set 600 even if I wanted.
Is there a better approach to opening an AWS instance's port to an Azure function app?

Comment: What is an "AWS E3 instance"? Are you talking about EC2? Are you talking about S3 (which doesn't have instances)?

Comment: @MarkB oops, yep, fixed to EC2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like using a NAT Gateway with AWS Lambda functions to provide a static outbound IP, it appears you can do the same thing in Azure Functions with a [Virtual network NAT gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses?tabs=portal#virtual-network-nat-gateway-for-outbound-static-ip). That appears to be your best option.

Comment: Thank you. It sounds like the Premium plan or Dedicated (App Service) plan is required for that approach, but we are on the Consumption Plan. For the moment I've noted the addresses that were used when scaling occurred, and many get reused. They fall into about 10 different CIDRs, so I added those to my AWS security group inbound rules as a stop gap. I won't be surprised if the next scaling event uses different addresses though. By then we make have moved our servers from AWS to Azure anyway. But your suggestion does sounds like a viable solution. Thanks